# clojure replace operator with its answer

Tags: clojure, lisp

I am trying to produce a function which takes the expression 'tree' as its argument and returns the tree with the relevant calculated values in place of the operators.

An example of what a tree could look like is:

```
(* (+ 10 (* 4 9)) (- 6 10))
```

And the function should return:

```
(-184 (46 10 (36 4 9)) (-4 6 10))
```

If anyone could provide me a solution or two and explain how they work to point me in the right direction, that would be great.

```
(def a '(* (+ 5 (* 3 7)) (- 6 8)) )

(defn evaltree [tree] (cons (eval (first (rest tree))) tree))
```

is all I have so far. It evals the first part of the list, but doesn't recurse through to do the rest of the list and doesn't replace the operator, it only adds the value to the beginning.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can show some code we can help you in finding the problems in it. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: (def a '(* (+ 5 (* 3 7)) (- 6 8)) )

(defn evaltree [tree]

  (cons (eval (first (rest tree))) tree))
all i have so far which evals the first part of list

Comment: @stevegarrid Add the code to the post, not as a comment.

Comment: This is quite a tricky problem. My first thought was to just get a function working which does what you're describing to a single S-expression. This is as simple as `(cons (eval tree) (rest tree))`. I thought the next step would be to apply this recursively over an entire tree, however this wouldn't work because we'd be transforming the tree from the inside-out, so the outer layers would be looking at things like `(2 1 1)` which are not eval-able.

Comment: One approach you might try is to build a new tree from scratch as you work your way from the inside-out of the input tree, but this is as complex as it sounds. IMHO, I think if you're just starting to learn Lisp, this type of problem might not be the best place to start.

Comment: This is a problem for Kent uni work learning lisp. So I have to do it unfortunately I can't just change to a simpler problem. It does seem extremely difficult since we only just started with lisp

Comment: I'm trying to deal with the problem starting with the smallest first so to deal with just a small list '(+ 2 9) however I can't seem to get eval to work in this situation (cons (eval tree) tree) I keep getting an unbound fn error and I can't seem to understand why

Comment: I think the basic idea must be to write function wich evals single list like '(+ 2 9), replaces the op with it's result, stores it somewhere, than returns the same list, so you can use it with maptree.

Answer (score 2):

The functions in clojure.walk are useful when you want to update arbitrary nested data structures, the following solution seems to work for this case.

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as w])

(defn op->answer [expr]
    (if (list? expr)
      (cons (eval expr) (rest expr))
      expr))

(w/prewalk op->answer '(* (+ 10 (* 4 9)) (- 6 10)))

;;=> (-184 (46 10 (36 4 9)) (-4 6 10))
```

clojore.walk/prewalk does a pre-order traversal of the expression tree and replaces each node with the return value from your function. You can see the order or calls with the following snippet.

```
(w/prewalk #(do (println %) %) '(* (+ 10 (* 4 9)) (- 6 10)))

;; => prints the following 
(* (+ 10 (* 4 9)) (- 6 10))
*
(+ 10 (* 4 9))
+
10
(* 4 9)
*
4
9
(- 6 10)
-
6
10
```

Comment: This is only semantically correct when applied to a purely functional language, though. Since your code evaluates the inner expressions multiple times side effects would occur multiple times. This also degrades performance.

Comment: If performance or side effects are an issue you can easily re-write the solution with postwalk with only a small increase in complexity. In general you should prefer higher order functions for this type of problem, they're generally simpler, easier to maintain and follow the 'principle of least surprise'. Since the set of operators is constrained in the example side effects aren't an issue and the prewalk solution is slightly simpler, it's always a good idea to avoid premature optimisation

Comment: I agree with you that one should prefer higher order functions, but I wouldn't call this "premature optimisation": The behaviour of your code is different from what one expects when seeing such an expression, because it doesn't have the same (or even similar) evaluation rules as Lisp (like) languages itself. Thus, IMO, this fails to follow the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 2):

Ain't that hard: As usual with such evaluators you have two cases you need to distinguish: Self evaluating values and calls (function application).

```
(defn evaluate
  [expression]
  (if (seq? expression) ;any sequence is a call with the operator in the first position
    (evaluate-call expression)
    expression))
```

Evaluating a call is done by first evaluating the operands/arguments. If one of these is a call by itself, then we'll get a sequence back. In the first position of this sequence will be - by induction - the result of the expression (since it's already evaluated).

```
(defn evaluate-call
  [expression]
  (let [arguments (map evaluate (rest expression))] ; evaluate arguments
    (cons (apply (get *functions* (first expression)) ; get function to apply
                 (map #(if (seq? %) (first %) %) arguments)) ; extract result from evaluated result, if neccessary
          arguments)))
```

Finally, we pack up our result into a sequence, together with the (evaluated) arguments (this is what the `cons` does).

Of course, we also need to define our available functions somewhere:

```
(def ^:dynamic *functions*
  {'+ +
   '- -
   '* *
   '/ /})
```

Running this code in CIDER (sorry, can't get ideone to work with clojure code) gives me:

```
evaluating.core> (evaluate '(* (+ 10 (* 4 9)) (- 6 10)))
;;=> (-184 (46 10 (36 4 9)) (-4 6 10))
```

Comment: Evaluate call doesn't seem to compile for me? It says unable to resolve evaluate call in this context. Any reason why? Thanks

Comment: Since these functions mutually call each other I guess you need to `(declare ...)` the one that's defined second.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive solution. You can return more than one value from a function; I take advantage of it by returning a pair: the value and the expansion you're looking for.

The structure is how you'd probably go about creating a lisp interpreter in which case you wouldn't need the second return value and would just return the value of the expression.

Here are the functions. `reval*` is implementation and `reval` unwraps the result:

```
(defn reval*
  [form]
  (cond
    (number? form) [form form]
    (list? form) (let [[op & rest] form
                       [vs forms] (->> rest
                                       (map reval*)
                                       (apply map list))
                       v (eval form)]
                   [v (conj forms v)])
    :else (throw (RuntimeException. "Unsupported form"))))

(defn reval
  [form]
  (second (reval* form)))
```

Note that I used `eval` as a shortcut but when creating an interpreter you'd probably use a hashmap similar to what @Daniel Jour has done -- `*functions` and use `(apply (*functions* op) vs)` instead.